# Termination conditions for Genetic Algorithm?

Tags: c#, genetic-algorithm

I'm using one that checks if the fittest chromosome in each generation has the same fitness for a number of generations (say.. 100) then the GA should terminate. But I don't think it's working efficiently, should it?

If not, what is/are the best termination criteria(s) for a genetic algorithm? 
I know I can end it after a number of generations or a time being, but I want the ones that imply on solutions and their fitness?

I don't understand these solutions btw,
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm#Termination

Comment: The description in the wiki page is very clear. What do you not understand?

Comment: "The highest ranking solution's fitness is reaching or has reached a plateau such that successive iterations no longer produce better results"

how will i determine this? ^

Comment: and is it different from what i've done?

Comment: it's exactly what you have done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This termination criteria might be dangerous for certain problems if you're using an elitist GA. The best solution would be kept from generation to generation and may be far better than any other solution. This then requires a number of generations for the rest of the population to catch up, which you would detect as stagnated. I would rather base the convergence detection on the average population quality as well as the best quality. Only if both have not improved, then convergence has occurred and you can stop.

Comment: you mean i should check all the individuals in one generation, and if there are too many chromosomes with the same fitness, i should terminate? 
wont that be too much inefficient? i mean, i will have to iterate a loop twice the population size!

Comment: and yes, i've used a bool for elitism, and i do mostly use it

Comment: and this algo seems right for GA if only im using permutation encoding.

Comment: No, you should compute the average fitness of your population and check if that has not improved over the last X generations. Yes, that's a little slower, but if you can integrate this into the evaluation phase you won't do any more work.